# How do I get a weekly automated reported for automations that ran in the last 7 days?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I'd like to set up a weekly automated report for all the Automations that ran in the last 7 days with a success or fail update. The goal would be to keep the email team more informed on what automations ran and what errored out.

I know we can sign up for notifications for success or failure for each automation individually; however, our team works with multiple BUs and those notifications can get overwhelming quickly.

So basically we're looking for a list of automations scheduled to run and the success/failure rate for each day.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed a similar solution for our client.

The idea is to use the [automation instance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automationinstance.htm) object in conjunction with ssjs. There is a field known as 'Status' which you can use to fetch the instance status. However, the catch is that this object does not accept and clause. That means you can't say all the automation instances that ran in last 7 days and have status = Error. Hence, you can go about this solution.

1. Fetch all the automation instances that ran in last 7 days. If you have less than 5 automations to monitor in each BU, you can utilize the IN Parameter and pass the automation customer key as an array. (The reason for 5 automations is that the limit for Customerkey value in the  filter is 400 characters)
2. For each automation instance, you can store the values in a DE.(Automation ID, Automation Name, Status)
3. Extract this and store on FTP, use [Attach File](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/) function in the email and send the email.
   All this will be part of an automation that you can schedule.

   ```
            var childreqID = null;
            var childprops = null;
            var childmoreObjs = true;
            prox.setClientId({"ID": mid});// You can use proxy,mid and run this in Parent BU for all BUs
            var AutomationInstance = "AutomationInstance";
            var childcols = ["CustomerKey","Status","StartTime","StatusLastUpdate","Name"];  
                        var childfilter = {

                        Property:"CustomerKey", 
                        SimpleOperator:"IN",
                        Value:  CustomerKey //Array of Customer Keys
                                        };

        try
        {

        while (childmoreObjs)
        {
            childmoreObjs = false;
            var childobjs = childreqID == null ? prox.retrieve(AutomationInstance, childcols, childfilter) : prox.getNextBatch(childobjs, childreqID);
        if (childobjs != null) 
            {
            childmoreObjs = childobjs.HasMoreRows;
        childreqID = childobjs.RequestID;
        var resultsStore = [];          
            for (var u = 0; u < childobjs.Results.length;u++)
            {  
                    var automationInsitanceObj = childobjs.Results[u]; 
                    var StartTime = automationInsitanceObj.StartTime;       
                    var customerkey = automationInsitanceObj.CustomerKey;
                    var instancestatus = automationInsitanceObj.Status;  
                    var AutomationName = automationInsitanceObj.Name
                    var today = new Date();
                    var prevDate = new Date();
                    var yesterday = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000*60*60*24); //Checking for automation in last 24 hours. You can modify for last 7 days
                    prevDate.setDate(today.getDate()-1);

        if(StartTime >= yesterday && instancestatus == -1) //Checking if this intnace is in  error
        {                 
        var rows  = Platform.Function.UpsertData('Automation_Monitoring',['MID','CustomerKey'],[mid,customerkey],['Status','ErrorDate','AutomationName','BusinessUnit','FolderName'],["Error",StartTime,AutomationName,marketName,foldername]);
        //Updating in  a DE    
        }         

        }//end for       
            }//end if
                }// end while
        }// end try

        catch (e)
        {
            Platform.Response.Write("child object error for" + Stringify(e)); 
        }
   prox.resetClientIds();
   ```